# A Godot tool script that adds a button the the inspector that opens a different scene

Tags: godot

Here's what I need but can't quite figure out:

I want a button on the Inspector of a particular node. When that button is clicked (during the editing, not when the game is running), I want to switch the editor to a different particular scene (or just open a new scene in a separate tab; either will do).

Is there a way for me to do it?

Comment: For what purpose do you need a new scene while running the game? Maybe what you need can be done with the debugger tab, which is quite powerful. I'm asking you this because I don't really understand what you need. In fact there's already a button ( https://imgur.com/HBU1jSu ) that generates a new scene -- that needs to be saved if you want to keep it -- but in the editor itself, not on the inspector of a particular node

Comment: Are you sure you don't simply want to export a `PackedScene` (for example: `export(PackedScene) var scene_file`). It is possible modify how properties show up in the inspector panel with an addon, however it is not clear on what nodes or what scene you should open, and exporting a `PackedScene` seems to do it already (you export the `PackedScene` from the node you want, and set it to the scene you want to open).

Comment: Rather than using [`tool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorscript.html#class-editorscript), if you want to add new functionality to the editor, you might use the [EditorPlugin](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorplugin.html#class-editorplugin) functions. It's easy to instance a different Scene in the current tree, but I strongly doubt you can just open a scene in a new tab: you may simply use the Scene name and filter it in the resource search bar instead.